# Incomplete directory listing when accessing a share

Tags: windows-7, server-message-block, cifs

I have a CIFS server configured as standAlone and I am trying to access a shared folder on it via a Windows 7 client. However, not all the files in the folder are listed. 
Network traces shows that the client sends a close2 request after a FindFirst and few FindNext requests, stopping the search midway.
This occurs only when I map the share. If i access it via Run, it works fine.
Any idea as to what might be happening here?

Comment: What do you mean `Access via Run`?

Comment: Just that I press Start -> run -> type the address of the share(\\server\folder) to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was problem with the one configuration parameter. The server was responding to open requests for files even though it was opening a directory. This caused the client to send a request to stop the enumeration in between.